# Linking images to routes in Laravel

Tags: html, routes, hyperlink, laravel, helper

I'm working on laravel php framework , I've a simple question ,
While using blade template engine , I normally use html helper functions
to render forms , links or whatever so .

Now when i try to put a link to specific route , i usually to like that :

```
{{ HTML::link_to_route('author','TheAuthor')) }}
```

First parameter takes the route , and the second one takes the string that will appear ,
To make it simpler that code will produce :

```
<a href="ROUTE URL">TheAuthor</a>
```

Now I want to replace TheAuthor with an image ,
What can i do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is not the answer you want to hear - but you cannot pass any image via link_to_route.

The problem is the output from the HTML class is escaped automatically. So if you try to pass this:

```
{{ HTML::link_to_route('author','<img src="'.URL::base().'assets/images/image.jpg" alt="icon" />')) }}
```

it comes out like this:

```
&lt;img src=&quot;http://laravel3.dev/assets/images/image.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;icon&quot; /&gt;
```

which will just be text on the screen - no image. Instead you need to use `URI::to_route('author')` and generate the link yourself. So make a helper a like this (not tested):

```
function link_to_route_image($route, $image)
{
   $m = '<a href="'.URL::to_route($route).'">'
      . '<img>'.$image.'</img>'
      . '</a>';
   return $m;
}
```

Comment: Actually is `HTML::linkRoute()`

Comment: Couldn't you just use `{!! HTML::link_to_route('author','<img src="'.URL::base().'assets/images/image.jpg" alt="icon" />')) !!}` ?

Comment: @MarcBrillault - no, because it is the function link_to_route() itself that does the escaping. Also - the code above using `{{ }}` was the old Laravel 4 output, where `{{ }}` was unescaped (unlike L5 where it is the other way around)

Comment: Users of other frameworks will wince at this omission.  Wrapping images in links is such a common task.  CakePHP, for example, has a parameter  'escape'=>false you can pass to it's equivalent of link_to_route() that allows you to pass icons or images as the title of the link.

Answer (score 11):

Or you can use {{route}}

Ex:

`<a href="{{route($route,$params)}}"><img src="'.$image.'" /></a>`

Answer (score 1):

It may become tedious if you are doing this all over the place, but in isolated spots the best way to handle this would actually be to wrap your entire link_to_* method call in HTML::decode.

```
{{ HTML::decode(HTML::link_to_route('author','<img src="{URL::base()}assets/images/image.jpg" alt="icon" />')) }}
```

There's nothing you can do from the inside of the function (such as wrapping the "title" portion in decode) because the cleaning is happening within the function call, but if you decode the entire link it will render the html properly.